# Is there any R package similar to 'tabout' in Stata

Tags: r, stata

Stata's tabout package is very useful in building publication quality tables (cross-tabulations) for export to a text file. Is there any such package for R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the package `stargazer` for producing publication quality tables.